# Unity5-GUI-HP-Bar Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've designed a custom HP bar and aligned it where I'd like it to be as well as how I'd like it to look.

[image: Supposed to look like this]

However, when I press play (Not full screen mode, haven't even tested for that)either the image background slides slightly right or the green filler image slides to the left.

[image: No supposed to look like this]

I have no idea why it's doing this or how to fix it. I'm willing to offer whatever information you require such as code or screenshots of the inspector.

This is a screen shot of the bar as it is in the sceneview canvas.

[image: Actual SceneView of the GUI bar]

[image: You can see that the bar works fine when NOT Playing the game]

As you can see when the Play isn't pressed the bar functions normally. The above pic is Half-Full. The below image is Empty.

[image: Supposed to look when empty]

Part 2 of the issue:

I'm also having trouble with the HP bar rotating properly with the player.

[image: Supposed to look like this]

However, when I turn left or right or face up:

[image: player Facing up bar should be behind not in front]

[image: Player Facing Right[![][8]]][9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA7QX.jpg)

So you can see the HP bar doesn't properly rotate with the player's movement; although it does follow perfectly, the bar doesn't rotate accordingly. I can provide some movement code and the code I use to track the position of the player. What I have done was created a sphere and attached it to the player. I then attached the script for tracking the player onto that sphere. I then removed the mesh render and box collider of the sphere.

Health Bar Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PHealth : MonoBehaviour {

[Header("HP Bar Images")]
[SerializeField]
private Image HpBarBG;
[SerializeField]
private Image HpBarFillBar;
private float imgFill = 1;





void Update () {
   FillBar()
}
private void FillBar(){
   HpBarFillBar.fillAmount = imgFill;
}


}
```

Player Movement Script

```
public GameObject player;
public Vector3 localscale;
// public Transform start, end;

[SerializeField]
private float speed = 5;



void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    /*
                ******** RAYCAST TO DETECT WALLS BELOW *******
     */
   //  WallDetection(); //Cast ray to detect walls

    /*
           *********      MOVEMENT CODE BELOW       *********
     */
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)|| Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) // Move 
        Forward
    {
        player.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime, 
        Space.World);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 180);
    }
    }//End of class
```

Comment: First guess is that the sprite (or UI element) isn't set to Pixel Perfect rendering, so its getting offset due to floating point math. The other problem is a separate question in the making. Also, for performance reasons, you should uncheck `raycast target` unless you want the player to be able to click on the object.

Comment: Yes, second question in the making. I wanted to make this topic as broad as possible so that I don't have to post another question.I'm going to look into the pixel perfect rendering and hopefully this is the answer! Finally, I appreciate the explanation of the raycast target. I was wondering about that! I'll let you know if the pixel perfect resolves the issue. Thanks bud! @Draco18s

Comment: Note: "too broad" is a reason to close questions. Stack Overflow focuses on single, answerable, questions.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed tat StackOverflow seems a bit whiny at times and strict about the little things. If I absolutely have to, I'll remove part 2 of my GUI related issue(Seems on topic to me...). Anyway, I cannot figure out where the UI element Pixel Perfect is.@Draco18s

Comment: Pixel perfect was actually on the Canvas itself. I was looking through the images and everywhere but there. Doh! Anyway, sadly enough, the pixel perfect being checked didn't work. Thanks for the advice on everything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend adding your code to your question so we have the full picture. Before you do that, I can only give you some recommendations and suggestions. **I'll amend this answer, so it becomes a real answer, afterwards.**

In the mean time, what type of canvas are you using? Judging from the hierarchy, I'd imagine it's in either of the screen space modes. Have you considered a world-space canvas parented to your player? I believe it'll naturally rotate in the way that you want it to. Can the players zoom in and out, and is the player character's rotation fixed to 90-degree increments?

In addition, are you *sure* you want the healthbar to rotate? To be upside down? Won't it be a better idea to keep it fixed in a regular position, above the character's sprite, even if that's technically "below" the character at the time?

Finally, if you don't mind me asking: why Unity 5? It's been a couple of major releases after it, and 2018 is almost at its cycle's end. Though to be fair, I don't know if the version will make any difference for this, so I'm just being curious.

Comment: While not wrong, this doesn't really answer the question, and would probably be better suited to a comment. I do understand that you don't have enough rep to leave a comment, answers such as these generally get closed.

Comment: I imagine that would be the case, but as noted in the first paragraph, I'll  gladly amend my answer to provide a solution once the extra details are provided. Furthermore, as a long-time lurker, I've seen plenty of suggestions of a similar note exist as answer. Nevertheless, I'll edit my post to make the notice clearer.

Comment: @vewonimire Thanks for your feedback. I'm currently using a Screen Space-Overlay canvas. I'll attempt to use the World Space camera and let you know if that resolves my issue. As far as rotation, I do not wish for it to rotate upsidedown. I only want it to follow in a fixed position behind the player regardless of direction. The game is 2-D top down with currently no zoom features. To satisfy your curiosity, I actually think I'm using Unity 2018 with one update available. However, I'm holding out for Unity 2019, which will be a very, very nice improvement! I can't wait!

Comment: @vewonimire Okay bro, I've tried the world space canvas and I had to resize the HP bar and re-coordinate it. No problem really. Now I run into the issue of when I press play, the HP bar disappears.My code isn't terribly complex. I'll post it at the top of the page A.S.A.P.

Comment: Ok, the solution was within your advice provided. I changed to world space, resized and positioned the bar. I had to remove the script from the sphere object I was using as a place holder, and deleted the place holder altogether. I then placed the canvas upon the player. The bar follows the player and turns. (Except when moving up, the bar stays in front of the player, but I'm not worried because I'm going to make it where the HP bar is only enabled when damaged and for only (x) amount  of time. I found your answer to be suitable because it gave me everything I needed to research.

Comment: Very glad to hear it, thanks! I can't wait for 2019 myself.

Comment: Despite being more comment that answer it looks like this was helpful. Should be able to edit this into an answer now, yeah? Either way, have the last +1 you need to be able to comment. :)